# Is it true that the centralizer of the action of a group $G$ on its subgroup $X$ by conjugation is the kernel of that action?

Tags: abstract-algebra

To elaborate my question, suppose $G$ is any group, $X$ is a subgroup and $G$ acts on $X$ by conjugation. Is it true that the kernel of this action is the same thing as the centralizer of $X$ in $G$?

Thanks,

Comment: What does it mean to be in the kernel? Write out the condition, and you will be enlightened.

Comment: "centralizer of the action" is poor word choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we get a permutation representation $\pi:G \rightarrow S_{X}$ given by $g \mapsto \sigma_g$ where $\sigma_g(x) = gxg^{-1}$. The kernel is all $g$ so that $\sigma_g$ is the identity, or in other words all the $g$ for which $gxg^{-1} = x$ for every $x \in X$. Writing this out in set notation, $$\ker\pi = \{g\in G \mid gx =xg, \forall x \in X\}$$ and this is precisely the centralizer of $X$ in $G$.

Alternatively, we can just consider the definition of the kernel of the action (which is the same as the kernel of the permutation representation associated with the action). This is defined as $$\ker = \{g\in G \mid g\cdot x = x,\forall x \in X\} = \{g\in G \mid gxg^{-1} = x,\forall x\in X\}$$ which is again the centralizer of $X$ in $G$. These are two valid approaches to establishing the kernel.